# Issue on prepopulating model value on view init in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to prepopulate an input field from my controller:

Here is the input field:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="partnerName" placeholder="Completeaza numele partenerului" ng-model="partnerNameModel.field" required validate-field="partnerNameModel">
```

In my controller,
If I do this:

```
partnerNameModel.field = 'test';
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'field' of undefined
```

So, I had to do it like this:

```
$scope.partnerNameModel = {field: 'dsad'};
```

I this good practice?

**Is there a better way to prepopulate fields?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the object partnerNameModel by doing

```
$scope.partnerNameModel = {}
```

at the top of your controller then you can use the dot syntax to set values like

```
$scope.partnerNameModel.value = "foo"
$scope.partnerNameModel.bar = "lemons"
```

This is how I personally work with objects in Angular

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with an input that has a placeholder, it makes sense to put no default value.

However, the object you are using must be created or it will be a big pain in the ass.

I recommend that you simply use:

```
$scope.partnerNameModel = {};
```

Make sure to initialize your fields that don't use a non-empty default value (a dropdown as an example).

```
$scope.partnerNameModel = {
    myDrop: $scope.myList[0]
};
```